# How to determine if store is open or closed using moment.js and moment timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

Am using `momentjs` in my website to determine whether a store is still open or closed based on the selected open, close time and timezone of the specific store location. The function i made works in some time range but doesn't in some.

JS LIBRARY

> /moment.js
>   /moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js

My Sample code

```
 function isOpen(openTime, closeTime, timezone){
  var  status = "closed";
  if(openTime != "24HR"){
    const  now = moment().tz(timezone);
    const  storeOpenTime = moment.tz(openTime, "h:mmA", timezone);
    const  storeCloseTime = moment.tz(closeTime, "h:mmA", timezone);
    /* const  storeOpenTime = moment.tz(Date.now(Date(openTime)), "h:mmA", timezone);
    const  storeCloseTime = moment.tz(Date.now(Date(closeTime)), "h:mmA", timezone);*/
    const  check = now.isBetween(storeOpenTime, storeCloseTime);
    if(check || check == true){
      status = "open";
    }
  }else{
    status = "open";
  }
  return status;
}
```

Let assume that the current time in malaysia kuala Lumpur is 11:34PM, and i run the below code

```
 isOpen("8:00AM", "12:20AM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur") 
 returned output = closed
```

The expected output for the above code is `open`, but if run the below code when the current time in malaysia kuala Lumpur is 11:34PM.

```
isOpen("8:00AM", "10:20PM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")
returned output = closed
```

The above output is correct.

Please my question is how do i use `momentjs` to check if time between open and close has passed using the country timezone?

Comment: Try using timestamp,so that it will be easy for comparison. Also easy to debug.

Comment: @SivaPasupathi using timestamp with existing function will it work?

Comment: @SivaPasupathi i have tried it using timestamp but it still doesn't work `isOpen("1577365200", "1577341800", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code corrected and commented:

```js
function isOpen(openTime, closeTime, timezone) {

  // handle special case
  if (openTime === "24HR") {
    return "open";
  }

  // get the current date and time in the given time zone
  const now = moment.tz(timezone);

  // Get the exact open and close times on that date in the given time zone
  // See https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/119
  const date = now.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  const storeOpenTime = moment.tz(date + ' ' + openTime, "YYYY-MM-DD h:mmA", timezone);
  const storeCloseTime = moment.tz(date + ' ' + closeTime, "YYYY-MM-DD h:mmA", timezone);

  let check;
  if (storeCloseTime.isBefore(storeOpenTime)) {
    // Handle ranges that span over midnight
    check = now.isAfter(storeOpenTime) || now.isBefore(storeCloseTime);
  } else {
    // Normal range check using an inclusive start time and exclusive end time
    check = now.isBetween(storeOpenTime, storeCloseTime, null, '[)');
  }

  return check ? "open" : "closed";
}

// Testing
const zone = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur";
console.log("now", moment.tz(zone).format("h:mmA"));
console.log("24HR", isOpen("24HR", undefined, zone));
console.log("2:00AM-8:00AM", isOpen("2:00AM", "8:00AM", zone));
console.log("8:00AM-2:00PM", isOpen("8:00AM", "2:00PM", zone));
console.log("2:00PM-8:00PM", isOpen("2:00PM", "8:00PM", zone));
console.log("8:00PM-2:00AM", isOpen("8:00PM", "2:00AM", zone));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.27/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

The main issue you had is that you have to work around the bug described in [issue #119](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/119), which is that when parsing time-only in a specific time zone, Moment incorrectly applies the UTC date instead of the tz-specific local date.

Secondarily, you also need to handle the case of the time range spanning over midnight, by checking for the open/close moments being out of sequence.  When they are, the comparison needs to be done differently - by checking if the current time is after opening or before closing.

Comment: Thanks for the help, please can you try it using your timezone, it still returning closed when I run this code

Comment: Updated the code to use the correct comparison technique when spanning over midnight.  Sorry I forgot about that in the original answer.  I also made it as a snippet so you can see it running.  One of the four ranges given should be open regardless of when you run the snippet (as well as the 24-hour one).

Comment: Hi, please you gave me good answer to this question last year, can you try helping me on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848371/how-to-check-if-open-to-close-time-has-elapse-using-timezone-in-javascript